# find first numeric value of first row and insert it at the end of second line, do it for multiples files in the same directory

Tags: loops, awk, insert, numeric

I have multiple files to process within a unique directory.
They share the same extension (.dat) but their name could be anything.
Each file has a 1st line made of a random text in which the first encountered numeric value has to be caught and then put at the end of the  2nd line.
Then many other lines after.

1st and 2nd line number of fields is unknown, as the position of the numeric value in the 1st row. 1st row can also include several numeric values.

This currently looks like as the example, with '850' in 'xxx.dat', file below:

*typical input:*

```
field11 field21 ... 850 ... 520 ... blabla ... 1100 ... fieldi1
field12 field22 ... fieldj2
field13 field23 ... fieldk3
...
field1n field2n ... fieldzn
```

*desired output:*

```
field11 field21 ... 850 ... 520 ... blabla ... 1100 ... fieldi1
field12 field22 ... fieldj2 850
field13 field23 ... fieldk3
...
field1n field2n ... fieldzn
```

Ideally a unique command or loop would process all the .dat files.

I am a beginner with sed and awk and unfortunately far from being able to solve this.
Please could I have any advice or solutions to do it ?
Thanks.

Comment: Please add to your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh

# make a temp file

trap "rm -f '$tmp'; exit" INT TERM

if command -v mktemp 2>&1 >/dev/null; then
    tmp=$(mktemp)
else
    tmp=edit.tmp
fi

[ -e "$tmp" ] && exit 1

# edit .dat files

for i in *.dat; do
    awk '
        NR==1 {while ($(++i) ~ /[^0-9]/); num=$i}
        NR==2 {print $0,num}
        NR!=2' "$i" > "$tmp"  &&
    mv "$tmp" "$i"
done

rm -f "$tmp"
```

It grabs the first digit only field in line 1, and appends it to line 2.

Run in a directory containing only `.dat`s you wish to edit.

It helps a lot to say which OS platform you're targeting.

Comment: Many thanks Dan. This works perfectly !  My OS is Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS